# I have deployed my contract using truffle but to see my accounts i am using web3 can any one explain what is going inside my contract while deploying

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, truffle-contract

web3.eth.accounts

```
[ '0x5aad8308d0c45d2b9fc1c465316ba071d2eb6f9c',
  '0x9d73990623df116eb56d300773aa458a11b11e4b',
  '0x1ea4dc6c3ab6d9ddca32083e3d5313ee319abd29',
  '0xd38587def59c78f8892e262005c73cca1bbab73b',
  '0xeb096207d34653763d662e0ba79ad3be3c39f706',
  '0x40f9dd5306881b4c73defacb295aeb185021b3b7',
  '0xddaf50fd9fb0d92368f8d6a6a3ff375ee61d96c1',
  '0xa401172dc8fe874f47cc4463cffc2dcc856ddf32',
  '0x47bd9beb52c3eadc41f981c626ec2cbd6e5422b7',
  '0xa51850dcd65e4ab4696923162ca8c8d352b12a8a' ]
```

I got all my accounts

In Truffle i have  deployed my contract as app

```
DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance){app = instance;})
```

When i typed

```
    app.accounts
    undefined
```

Can anyone explain what is going inside deploying and why we can't see when typing `app.accounts` and why can we see when using `web3.eth.accounts`

i didn't find any documention can any one elobrate it and explain

**i am trying everything in the console**

Comment: Did you call deployer.deploy before that?

Comment: I have done succefuly deployed using deploye.deploy()

Comment: Why are you expecting to see app.accounts? Do you have a field in your contract with this name? You can only call functions on contracts.

Comment: NO but i am thinking why can we see accounts web3.eth.accounts when we have no accounts specified

Comment: If you see a result returned by web3.eth.accounts, you’re connected to a node which manages these accounts.

Comment: Thanks 

do Truffle deployment is not connected node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why we can't see when typing app.accounts

You see nothing by calling this, because basically you can only call functions of the contract via contract's instance (and few other things like the address of the contract, etc.)

> why can we see when using web3.eth.accounts

Because your node is managing these accounts.

Please check the [Ethereum tutorial](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/), [truffle documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/overview) and [web3 api specification](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).